# How to narrow function parameter type

Tags: typescript

Long story short, the `addEntry` function in `BuilderUsingPlugins` should be using the `pluginValueType` to determine what `pluginParams` should be. However, this isn't actually narrowing `pluginValueType`. It is creating a union of all the `createEntry` parameters of all the passed plugins.

What I want is `pluginParams` to not be a union type of all parameter types of all the `addEntry` functions. I want it to be the parameter type of the plugin in `plugins` that has the key `pluginValueType`.

```js
type plugin = {
  name:string,
  createEntry(...params:any[]):any
}
type PluginMap<T extends ReadonlyArray<plugin>> = {
  [key in T[number] as key["name"]]: key["createEntry"] extends ((...args:any[])=>any)? key["createEntry"]:never
}


type valueStore<T extends ReadonlyArray<plugin>> ={ 
    [k in string]: ReturnType<T[number]["createEntry"]>
  }
type storeEntry<k extends string,T extends (...args:any)=>any>={
  store:{
    [key in k]:ReturnType<T>
  }
}


class BuilderUsingPlugins<T extends ReadonlyArray<plugin>> {
  store: valueStore<T> = { }
  plugins: PluginMap<T>
  addEntry(
    pluginValueType: keyof PluginMap<T>,
    name: string,
    ...pluginParams: Parameters<PluginMap<T>[keyof PluginMap<T>]> extends Parameters<PluginMap<T>[typeof pluginValueType]>? Parameters<PluginMap<T>[keyof PluginMap<T>]> :never
  ): this & storeEntry<string extends keyof this["store"]? never:string,ReturnType<PluginMap<T>[typeof pluginValueType]>> {
    this["store"][name] = this.plugins[pluginValueType as keyof PluginMap<T>](pluginParams)
    return this as this & storeEntry<string extends keyof this["store"]? never:string,ReturnType<PluginMap<T>[typeof pluginValueType]>>
  }
  constructor(params:T){
    this.plugins = params.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
      return {
        ...acc,
        ...{[curr.name]:curr.createEntry} as const satisfies PluginMap<[typeof curr]>
      }
    },{} ) as PluginMap<typeof params>
  }
}
const fooPlugin={
  createEntry(){
    return 'I am the "foo" plugin!'
  },
  name:"foo"
} as const satisfies plugin

const barPlugin = {
  name:"bar",
  createEntry(someparam:number){
    return someparam
  }
} as const satisfies plugin

const MyPluginList = [fooPlugin,barPlugin] as const 
const builder = new BuilderUsingPlugins<typeof MyPluginList>(MyPluginList)
builder.addEntry("bar","barEntry")
// @ts-expect-error
builder.addEntry("foo","fooEntry")
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-dqTOYLGEmFzCKQHSSATmudTvahdOJJNUKxIyFwaLqtYYM6K4gkU2nm4GswpIvrOnpK3Wco3-S2s3Jdh2yzHDgne5Ma-n66P092wm2QB2m2hx2Fe1AVutNgQVFBgAALZDOABkWNO7DDZkLiEJA6Tqcv17q9oqk1WGw0FQtCkgKoLgpCZg7gGmYblOqYzrG8aQr2kSclyX6UD+D4QBUaT5nkWCYUIZZYYhc6QvkhTtqm0F7goAhlkuJCUEoEbsIK6CYVR55Xre944k+L5vtcH68d+xS-go-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)

Comment: ① Do you have your "expect-error" backwards? ② Could you fix your type and type parameter names to be more conventional (types should be in UpperPascalCase; type parameters should be uppercase letters like `K`, not lowercase words like `key`; `T[number]` is not keylike so the name of the type parameter shouldn't be `key` in any case, etc.) ③ Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mbyEEN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer (after you make the suggested edits from before). If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix the issue with generics and type assertion.
`BuilderUsingPlugin` now looks like this

```js
class BuilderUsingPlugins<T extends ReadonlyArray<plugin>> {
  store = { }
  plugins: PluginMap<T>
  addEntry<P extends T[number]["name"],K extends PropertyKey>(
    pluginValueType: P,
    name: K,
    ...pluginParams: Parameters<UsingPluginMap<T,P>>
  ): this & storeEntry<K,UsingPluginMap<T,P>> {
    let newStore = {...this["store"]}
    this.pointlessAssertion<typeof this["store"],K,ReturnType<UsingPluginMap<T,P>>>(newStore,name,this.plugins[pluginValueType](pluginParams))
    this.store = {...newStore} as const satisfies typeof newStore
    return {...this} as this & storeEntry<K,UsingPluginMap<T,P>>
  }
  private pointlessAssertion<T extends object,K extends PropertyKey,V>(t:T,k:K,v:V): asserts t is T &{[key in K]:V}{
    Object.assign(t,{[k]:v})
  }

  constructor(params:T){
    this.plugins = params.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
      return {
        ...acc,
        ...{[curr.name]:curr.createEntry} as const satisfies PluginMap<[typeof curr]>
      }
    },{} ) as PluginMap<typeof params>
  }
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBGA2CuBzAlgOygXigbwFBSlQEMBbCALgGdgAnNRAGnygGMaIjgIBRVWkABQA6EWCI1SlckVQgA2gF0AlNNm4AvrlCQoABQQpUAWSJgAPABUoEAB5dUAE0pQAShwcB7VLBABBGhIgZnBIaAB8YZg4zHIA1hAgUGhQFnKo8CQARhA0ClBEzvHyAETEZMUKCuRQRXLFbBxcvPwV1nYQjs4CwiLiiFIy8soYYYNKAPw1CXUNnDx8NCAV5KgQAG45Grjb2tBrRAgQAMrAHuyWbfZOru5ePv6BwQbhkRjYUMwEcUno1HSoiCqN2A8BoqAs4AgljSGWyuRm7DmzUWFTCzE0uyg1DO834Zlilw6110NA8kBooAA0gkGFZbFcuiIhH0BrIlCNBmE3sxsexyHgCF8ij8alU3CCwRDIJY0QRNJotJCoABVSj0fShYymC70onONxETzePwBIhBEKGMIMKDUxK6zopGFZHIKOplCCojAawwmcwWMJyW0KXAsWAFZwAIXgyFgDhyqvVz1QlB17QdBqN91N5qTEWiBF50Cw700BAtaCkeiTvplzENDmRQV0hIdqXSzvhpVIHoUDEpLeJpPJVISYQEnxgSYAagd4BApRQ9ExBYRu9VKcvBUzy6hdOJJNU9xIyFwaCmEwDvWgaxYGLoIswVFBgAALZDOABkWNO7EbZg3F6IFeWp+neeYCoKsAQMAhAQAA7icOJRNgTKvu+dSFhUpaCmhlBCGAHhoMAUGUJQvikTkwDIF4Zi7B4ABmz5vpQGE-j2fYMOKoLgpCZiAcBN5gREAirAhbEMO6DC4fhSYsTuM6HAuCgCDuR6SEoSgTtJhbIUyomIew6j5M4LBeNQWKcO+9HIBAzh0Yx+lsRO7ASugKEiLhRkFEx75QF+hZ-gBaqXtW2q3vespQNhYB0PsXAwIRfAkWRFEUtRqCpgyUAeJkABWEAsMAfYDs4JJkpRIC2gwU5jsA5C3rE5Abms5BTk+4aUXZSTOFYH7YHECQipSVRTuoEEEAA8nlBXAMypHIIgqACEV-WxFUazqJpcrbAQpnJrQ8CFWcKn7iQUgWEo40+XhO7OFgYjHnh7AOIdEDdEQLAsAwLCgjQ7JhFdBAudx+YrluvSfZuYNQEy-U-QEQjulU8M0EIsxNAsIBeSZZkwZQlmUNZtlVpqNZyPZrC-QokUrthcoMNgRlKMZJM+tqFMPZIkUKpoe3mfRHgeMB3K7YiGP8AIl3OdBIMAOQAJL5CQTHQMUAseMUk6agAhLL6Kbu65Bq4LxQaCzfN4wTRPODu2wW1AmTiMByHMIbxSOzQxSbujuKLAIlAeGQnMkCssI5Co7ZwldwNgligcQMH6Jm959v41RhM2TbSZ27jDtEAAXs7xau2u7sF17zA+42AgdBk74vv4iDkHUL4QLAsAawwxRwWcsYVE6cLKM3xSt+3nfd73Dj95HLrRzLse1yQ9eN0n2OsLnadWZnWuGCGueO9iReg27B+nBXouNL7giL2A5AZncJqPH89BhCoFM33PrnWO2YAs+-P+r3NhvK229bb2yMCAYCAAZd8MEsByHVsBBgHskGO0LkmZBBRTjATyCnXOe99oO2jLGHIURRJQCjDGOMNB+KyVopCBiUAIHQNgWOZhSYYHUE0tsAA9AAKj4fgPheghykJyKSM8UAXxnECNrIRPDcA8J4VAAAAsASgABaWwkBCpaICGcXAmRiHUOZA4BsmMBDG3HurRsXsAAsmklGCgAHrjEUTwtRmjtEzT0RIwxxicimPMRLMunsu4e1sQwbhQA)